# Working with PDFs in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, pdf, pdfkit

I am wondering if there is a way to use the simpler classes in PDFKit (PDFDocument, PDFPage), and still get references to the lower level CGPDFDocumentRef object.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From PDFDocument.h:

```
// This is the CGPDFDocument associated with the PDFDocument 
// object.  With this object you can call many CoreGraphics 
// API. May return NULL if the document was not created from 
// an existing PDF file or data.
- (CGPDFDocumentRef) documentRef;
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I looked at least 10 times.  Thanks for your help and excuse my lack of attention to detail.

Comment: @grivescorbett: No apology necessary; I didn't know about it either, so I learned something, and I'm glad I was helpful.